# Unable to add API DLL as a reference to the windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am developing a windows phone application, in that I am using an API DLL where I need to use all classes, methods, properties from that API DLL and when I add API DLL as reference to my windows phone application it is giving an exception as "A reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project".
How can I solve this? can anyone please suggest a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can only add a `Windows Phone/Silverlight Class Library` or `Portable Class Library for Windows Phone` to your Windows Phone project because some API in standard .NET Framework is not available in Windows Phone.

If your API library is targeted to standard .NET Framework, you will be needed to rewrite it to retarget to Windows Phone compatible frameworks.